# Sourcetree unable to push commit to GitHub

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I wasn't able to push a commit to the repository. Below is the message I got from Sourcetree. I am using a Mac.

```
git --no-optional-locks -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

> Pushing to https://username@github.com/username/repo.git remote:
>   Permission to username/repo.git denied to username. fatal: unable to
>   access 'https://username@github.com/username/repo.git/': The requested
>   URL returned error: 403

Comment: Well, the error message is clear. You’ve got a bad username / password pair here. It might help to work this out at the command line.

Comment: In the Sourcetree **Preferences (`cmd` + `,`)** => **Accounts** => **Edit** => _Update the Username/Password_. Try that if not switch to **OAUTH** instead of basic authentication.

Comment: Hi! I couldn't find the place to update the username/password. I am using 3.1.1 sourcetree and this is what I have under my accounts=>edit is auth type (oauth), username, protocol (https)

Comment: The username part already showed my connected github account. I was also able to click on the "connect account" under my username but that just led me to a blank github page

Comment: @matt do you how to do so...